# SwiftUI: dismiss List searchable keyboard?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view that uses searchable. I would like do dismiss the keyboard programmatically if user starts scrolling on the List. Same behavior as you see in the Contacts app.

```
@State var query:String = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                } label: {
                    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .searchable(text: $query, prompt: Text("search"))
        .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
            /// <-- dismiss keyboard??
        }))
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditButton()
            }
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        Text("Select an item")
    }
}
```

I can detect the scroll event, but, I am not sure how to actually dismiss the keyboard.

I saw some approaches using `endEditing` on the view... but, I wonder about using `focuseScope`. I found some information about it here:

https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/12/02/focus-management-in-swiftui/

How can I dismiss the keyboard, and preferably, use `focus` instead of calling something generic on the whole view?

Comment: The `searchable` is out of SwiftUI scope focus management (it is part of search controller representable, actually), so that `endEditing` is the only way for now. If it would be regular TextField then it will be ok to use focused to remove keyboard.

Comment: yes, and then you could use `focusState`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `dismissSearch` environment value to get the `DismissSearchAction` instance for the current Environment. Then call the instance to dismiss the current search interaction.

When you dismiss the search, SwiftUI sets `isSearching` to false and removes focus from the search field.

```
@State var query:String = ""
@Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                } label: {
                    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
        }
        .searchable(text: $query, prompt: Text("search"))
        .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ _ in
            dismissSearch()
        }))
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                EditButton()
            }
            ToolbarItem {
                Button(action: addItem) {
                    Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        Text("Select an item")
    }
}
```